# Counting instances of first name and last name, whilst also getting users conditionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a little stuck on a query and I am struggling with an example.

Currently I have two queries:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, COUNT(*) instance 
FROM Customer 
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY instance DESC
```

This gets me all users by firstname and lastname, and a count of how many there are, basically I am using this to make sure I don't have duplicate user entries. This works fine.

I then have a second query - I can't modify this database, as someone else created and productionised it, and I need to get an email address from another table as follows:

```
SELECT c.PK_CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, u.Email
FROM Customers c, Users u
WHERE c.Location = 2 AND c.FK_UserID = u.PK_UserID
ORDER BY c.PK_CustomerID ASC
```

So that gets me what I want. However now I want to have it where I get the customer ID, the firstname and lastname, the email in the other table... but I also want to get a count of how many other people have the same first and last name.

So basically I'm getting the full details I wanted, and I am alerted to the fact that someone out there shares a first and last name (so I know I haven't duplicated my customers).

I'm really stuck on this, I tried an INNER JOIN but I didn't know how to incorporate my where conditions

Comment: Use proper `JOIN` syntax.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Window Functions for this (Assuming Sql Server 2008 or newer):

Add to your second query: `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.firstname, c.lastname) as instance` that will give you a count of how many other records share the same first and lastname with the current record.

```
SELECT c.PK_CustomerID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, u.Email
   ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c.firstname, c.lastname) as instance
FROM Customers c, Users u
WHERE c.Location = 2 AND c.FK_UserID = u.PK_UserID
ORDER BY c.PK_CustomerID ASC
```

Comment: Did you encourage the OP to use the old style joins?

Comment: @Sami I just decided to focus on the question at hand. I hate old style joins, but I see them so much in production code that I've just grown to accept that as long as it's supported by their RDBMS, people are going to do it.